# How to activate optional 'registration_id' in results[] response?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

FCM documentations talks about a 'optional' field in results[] response, but neither about how to activate this option. I would like a different solution that indexed positions requests way.

[Table 5 firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)